# How to protect password in Selenium scripts

Tags: security, selenium, automated-tests

I am  writing selenium (seleno) scripts to test a c# MVC web application which requires users to log in. At the moment the username and password are hard-coded into the script but I need to make sure the password is protected before I can commit the scripts to our code repository.

The scripts will be run autonomously through CI (TeamCity) so the password must be available to the program without any human input.

In terms of security requirements, the password is common knowledge amongst devs but it is also bundled with the software that is deployed to clients (which obviously opens a back door to anyone in possession of the password - for better or for worse). So if someone gains access to our codebase we need to be sure that they cant get at the password. The password itself is stored (salted) in a sqlite database.

If I pass an encrypted value into the program and then decrypt it will that protect us? Im not too bothered about the password being in memory on the server where the test runs as that server should be securely locked down and will only exist for the duration of the tests.

The only other thing I can think of is to insert a temp password into the sqlite database once TeamCity has spun up the temp server instance and before the tests are run. Not sure how to achieve that though.

I would have thought this would be a really common problem with selenium but I havent as yet been able to find a definitive solution.

Comment: "if someone gains access to our codebase" then you have completely different problems! "I  would have thought this would be a really common problem with selenium" ... protesting **test** passwords is a waste of effort, so it is generally not a problem. Can't you have test accounts/passwords that are removed the the db before shipping the app to the customers?

Comment: I noticed your comment about you do not know how to insert temp passwords. That is easy: go grab a Coke, head over to your db developer, and make a friend. Get him to explain to you "JDBC".

Comment: You're approaching the problem from the wrong angle. Managing the test passwords is something that is *highly* dependent on the server software you are running. I do it in a certain way for one of my Django apps but telling you how I do it would not be particularly useful for you. SiKing gave you one option: talk to the DB directly. You could also have views that exist only during testing that could help you do this without having to talk directly to the DB. Or you could have an ad-hoc wire protocol to do it (which is what I do).

Comment: Thanks for your comments folks. Seems the only way to go is to have a test specific account. So I have written a batch script which will insert a user record using sqlite command line tool and will just need to configure TeamCity to run the script prior to kicking off the test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SiKing suggests, the solution is to use a temporary, test specific password which wont make it into production code. Simples.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set your passwords at runtime. I would suggest environment variables. Then they are not in your codebase and instead somebody would need to hack into where you run your tests from.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I have used is to execute javascript to evaluate things:

```
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>prompt(&quot;What password&quot;)</td>
<td>secretPassword</td>
```

That only really works for user run stuff via webdriver though.

You *could* setup some kind of small ajax request at the start of the test to http://localhost/credentials.json or similar, which is set up on your CI instance (but not available anywhere else).

Answer (score 0):

Add a password manager extension like bitwarden,keepass etc.., and configure it to auto-login... give 2-3 sec in code to auto-login